# Error: Cannot convert from 'method group' to string

Tags: c#

Getting error which says Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'. Error is in the function `MapEventsAndTypes`. Here is the error: `options => options.MapFrom(MapEventsAndTypes));`

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<EventTypeDTO, EventType>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<EventCreationDTO, Event>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Poster, options => options.Ignore())
                .ForMember(x => x.EventAndEventTypes, options => options.MapFrom(MapEventsAndTypes)); 
                  ////////error at 'MapEventsAndTypes'
           
            CreateMap<SportTypeDTO, SportType>().ReverseMap();

        }

        private List<EventAndEventType> MapEventsAndTypes(EventCreationDTO eventCreationDTO, Event events)
        {

            var result = new List<EventAndEventType>();
            if (eventCreationDTO.TypeIds == null)
            {
                return result;
            }
            foreach( var id in eventCreationDTO.TypeIds)
            {
                result.Add(new EventAndEventType() { EventTypeId = id });
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

class with propery EventAndEventTypes
exact error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

```
namespace EventsAndTicketsAPI.Entities
{
    public class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 75)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int TicketPrice { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Poster { get; set; }
        public List<EventAndEventType> EventAndEventTypes { get; set; } 

    }
}
```

class EventAndEventType

```
public class EventAndEventType
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public int EventTypeId { get; set; }
    public Event Event { get; set; }
    public EventType EventType { get; set; }
}
```

}

class EventCreationDTO

```
public class EventCreationDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TicketPrice { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Poster { get; set; }
    [ModelBinder(BinderType=typeof(TypeBinder<List<int>>))]
    public List<int> TypeIds { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you share class where you have property EventAndEventTypes?

Comment: And the specific row that gives the error, and the exact error text.

Comment: Pretty sure you're just missing ().

Comment: 'Cannot convert from 'method group'' usually means you have written `MyMethod` instead of `MyMethod()`. I.e. the compiler thinks you want to convert a method to a delegate instead of just calling it.

Comment: can you share EventAndEventType class, what is the EventTypeId  type and what is id type in ```var id in eventCreationDTO.TypeIds```

Comment: Hi, I just shared it

Comment: I'm guessing `MapFrom` is from AutoMapper, I'm not familliar with that library, but it is probably used incorrectly. Check the documentation, the compiler thinks you want to call the overload with a string parameter, but I'm guessing you want some other overload.